# \rowcolor doesn't fill complete cell

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor

I use a template to create use cases in latex ([Template information)](https://tom.desair.me/blog/2012/04/latex-template-for-use-cases/). This is how it normaly looks:

[image]

The latex source to use it looks like this:

```
\begin{usecase}     
\addtitle{test text to show the rowcolor}
\addfield{user:}{test}
\addfield{conditions:}{test}
\addscenario{secnario}{
    \item test
}
\addfield{result:}{test}
\end{usecase}
```

I want to change the background color of the title and the result field. To archieve this, i edited the template:

```
% Initial source for the title
\newcommand\addtitle[1]{ \hline \\ [-1.5ex] \multicolumn{2}{p{15cm}}{\textbf{#1}}\\ [1ex] \hline \\ [-1.5ex]}
% Modified to add color to the title
\newcommand\addtitle[1]{ \hline \\ [-1.5ex] \rowcolor{Gray}  \multicolumn{2}{p{15cm}}{\textbf{#1}}\\ [1ex] \hline \\ [-1.5ex]}
%
% Initial Source to add a filed
\newcommand\addfield[2]{\textit{#1} &#2\\ [1ex] \hline \\ [-1.3ex] }
% New command for the result, same as addfield but with color
\newcommand\addresult[2]{ \rowcolor{Gray} \textit{#1} &#2\\ [1ex] \hline \\ [-1.3ex] }
```

This creates following output:

[image]

How do I have to change the template to have a colored background for the whole width and height?

This is compilable example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV14,BCOR10mm,a4paper,parskip=half-,headsepline,headinclude]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[headsepline,headinclude,automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{usecases}
\definecolor{Gray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\begin{document} 
   \chapter{UseCaseTest}
   \the\textwidth
   \begin{usecase}     
      \addtitle{test text to show the rowcolor}
      \addfield{user:}{test}
      \addfield{conditions:}{test}
      \addscenario{scenario}{
         \item test
      }
      \addresult{result:}{test}
    \end{usecase}
\end{document}
```

which produces following output:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Which documentclass do you use? How wide is your text width? How wide should your table be? How is the color `Gray` defined?...

Comment: you should never have `\\ ` after `\hline` so  you need to at least delete `\\ [-1.5ex]`  but please make a small complete document that shows the problem without referencing external sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you to work in the right direction

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{TopRow}{rgb}{0.4,0.7,1}
\definecolor{NormalRow}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}

\newcommand\addrow[2]{#1 &#2\\ }

\newcommand\addheading[2]{#1 &#2\\ \hline}
\newcommand\tabularhead{\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm}}\rowcolor{TopRow}
\hline
}

\newcommand\addmulrow[2]{ \begin{minipage}[t][][t]{2.5cm}#1\end{minipage}% 
   &\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{8cm}
    \begin{enumerate} #2   \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}\\ }

\newenvironment{usecase}{\tabularhead}
{\hline\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

% Initial Source to add a filed
\newcommand\addfield[2]{\textit{#1} &#2\\ [1ex] \hline \\ [-1.3ex] }
% New command for the result, same as addfield but with color
\newcommand\addresult[2]{\rowcolor{NormalRow}\textit{#1} & #2\\ [1ex] \hline \\ 
 [-1.3ex] }
 \begin{usecase}     
      \addheading{test text to show the rowcolor}{}
      \addfield{user:}{test}
      \addfield{conditions:}{test}
      \addmulrow{scenario}{
         \item test
      }
      \addresult{result:}{test}
    \end{usecase}
\end{document}
```